# Centering a Poem using Verse package

Tags: formatting, verse

I'm trying to center a poem on my document and I'm using the `verse` package to include line numbers on the poem. Here is my code:

```
    \section{Poem}
    \poemtitle{Another Day}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    \poemlines{2}
    \begin{altverse}
    having the low down blues and going \\ 
into a restraunt to eat.\\ 
you sit at a table.\\ 
the waitress smiles at you.\\ 
she's dumpy. her ass is too big.\\ 
she radiates kindess and symphaty.\\ 
live with her 3 months and a man would no real agony.\\ 
o.k., you'll tip her 15 percent.\\ 
you order a turkey sandwich and a\\ 
beer. the man at the table across from you\\ 
has watery blue eyes and\\ a head like an elephant.\\ 
at a table further down are 3 men\\ 
with very tiny heads\\ 
and long necks\\ 
like ostiches.\\ 
they talk loudly of land development.\\ 
why, you think, did I ever come\\ 
in here when I have the low-down\\ 
blues?\\ 
then the the waitress comes back eith the sandwich\\ 
and she asks you if there will be anything\\ 
else?\\ 
snd you tell her, no no, this will be\\ 
fine.\\ 
then somebody behind you laughs.\\ 
it's a cork laugh filled with sand and\\ 
broken glass.\\ 
\vspace{0.4cm}
you begin eating the sandwhich.\\ 
\vspace{0.4cm} 
it's something.\\ 
it's a minor, difficult,\\ 
sensible action\\ 
like composing a popular song\\ 
to make a 14-year old\\ 
weep.\\ 
you order another beer.\\ 
jesus,look at that guy\\ 
his hands hang down almost to his knees and he's\\ 
whistling.\\ 
well, time to get out.\\ 
pivk up the bill.\\ 
tip.\\ 
go to the register.\\ 
pay.\\ 
pick up a toothpick.\\ 
go out the door.\\ 
your car is still there.\\ 
and there are 3 men with heads\\
and necks\\
like ostriches all getting into one\\
car.\\
they each have a toothpick and now\\
they are talking about women.\\
they drive away first\\
they drive away fast.\\
they're best i guess.\\
it's an unberably hot day.\\
there's a first-stage smog alert.\\
all the birds and plants are dead\\
or dying.\\
\vspace{0.4cm}
you start the engine.
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}
```

This yields the following:

[image: Snip 1]
[image: Snip 2]

I want it to be centered like the poem title. Could this be fixed?

I added `3in` to the code where `[\versewidth]` is and it yields:

[image: Snip 3]

But, I'd like for it to look more like this:

[image]

Comment: perhaps change `\versewidth` to something like `3in` in the optional argument...

Comment: That centers it but not quite exactly what I need...I'll edit my post and show you what I mean.

Comment: Please make sure that you have a compilable example somewhere. It is way easier for the answerers to have one. Regarding the comparison of the last two example pics you should keep in mind that the font differs.

Comment: The last example pic is from a pdf of the poem that's not even created in LaTex I just want my render to have the same centering as that and also include line numbers...I just added that comparison photo for simplicity.

Comment: @Ruben is asking you to complete your code to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). We want code we can copy-paste-compile. Also, reduce the length of the poem in your MWE unless the length is crucial for somebody to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found no way to accomplish the verse centering using the facilities of the package.  So, what I did was to set each line in a `\makebox` of a fixed (but tuned) size, as defined by the macro `\CC`.  So you need to wrap each line in a `\CC` wrapper, which is the downside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\CC#1{\makebox[4in]{#1}}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
    \section{Poem}
    \poemtitle{Another Day}
    \begin{verse}[\textwidth]
\vgap=0pt\relax
    \poemlines{2}
    \begin{altverse}
%
\CC{having the low down blues and going}\\ 
\CC{into a restraunt to eat.}\\ 
\CC{you sit at a table.}\\ 
\CC{the waitress smiles at you.}\\ 
\CC{she's dumpy. her ass is too big.}\\ 
\CC{she radiates kindess and symphaty.}\\ 
\CC{live with her 3 months and a man would no real agony.}\\ 
\CC{o.k., you'll tip her 15 percent.}\\ 
\CC{you order a turkey sandwich and a}\\ 
\CC{beer. the man at the table across from you}\\ 
\CC{has watery blue eyes and}\\ \CC{a head like an elephant.}\\ 
\CC{at a table further down are 3 men}\\ 
\CC{with very tiny heads}\\ 
\CC{and long necks}\\ 
\CC{like ostiches.}\\ 
\CC{they talk loudly of land development.}\\ 
\CC{why, you think, did I ever come}\\ 
\CC{in here when I have the low-down}\\ 
\CC{blues?}\\ 
\CC{then the the waitress comes back eith the sandwich}\\ 
\CC{and she asks you if there will be anything}\\ 
\CC{else?}\\ 
\CC{snd you tell her, no no, this will be}\\ 
\CC{fine.}\\ 
\CC{then somebody behind you laughs.}\\ 
\CC{it's a cork laugh filled with sand and}\\ 
\CC{broken glass.}\\ 
\vspace{0.4cm}
\CC{you begin eating the sandwhich.}\\ 
\vspace{0.4cm} 
\CC{it's something.}\\ 
\CC{it's a minor, difficult,}\\ 
\CC{sensible action}\\ 
\CC{like composing a popular song}\\ 
\CC{to make a 14-year old}\\ 
\CC{weep.}\\ 
\CC{you order another beer.}\\ 
\CC{jesus,look at that guy}\\ 
\CC{his hands hang down almost to his knees and he's}\\ 
\CC{whistling.}\\ 
\CC{well, time to get out.}\\ 
\CC{pivk up the bill.}\\ 
\CC{tip.}\\ 
\CC{go to the register.}\\ 
\CC{pay.}\\ 
\CC{pick up a toothpick.}\\ 
\CC{go out the door.}\\ 
\CC{your car is still there.}\\ 
\CC{and there are 3 men with heads}\\
\CC{and necks}\\
\CC{like ostriches all getting into one}\\
\CC{car.}\\
\CC{they each have a toothpick and now}\\
\CC{they are talking about women.}\\
\CC{they drive away first}\\
\CC{they drive away fast.}\\
\CC{they're best i guess.}\\
\CC{it's an unberably hot day.}\\
\CC{there's a first-stage smog alert.}\\
\CC{all the birds and plants are dead}\\
\CC{or dying.}\\
\vspace{0.4cm}
\CC{you start the engine.}
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple answer and straight to the point! You rock!