# Aligning text to the right inside a verse

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verse, ragged2e

Inside a `verse` environment as provided by the [verse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verse) package how would I align an entire stanza to the right? I'm looking for something like the below:

[image]

Neither `\raggedleft` nor `\RaggedLeft` as provided by [ragged2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) provide the intended result. Prepending `\hfill` to each line simply centers it.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `verse` environment specifically? Why not define a new `rightverse` (or whatever) environment? (Also, have you tried `\hfilll` instead of `\hfill`?)

Comment: I'd like to be able to use multiple different alignments inside one environment if possible. I have not tried `\hfilll` as the solution I posted below solved it before I got any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most practical solution, but here's an attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}
\newlength\alignverserightwidth
\newcommand\alignverseright[1]{
    \settowidth{\alignverserightwidth}{#1}
    \hspace{\versewidth}\hspace{-\alignverserightwidth}#1
}

\begin{document}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{it should}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        \alignverseright{This} \\
        \alignverseright{is} \\
        \alignverseright{how} \\
        \alignverseright{it should} \\
        \alignverseright{look} \\
    \end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that was the only approach I could find, as well, for centering: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214600/centering-a-poem-using-verse-package/214619#214619